# How to keep rows if there are a certain number of observations based on the first column?

Tags: text-processing

I have a file that looks like the example below. 
The first column is SNP id.

```
head data
2L:647803 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:647803 1 2 43.63717 -12.302
2L:647803 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:2602906 1 2 43.39748 -11.4894
2L:2602906 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:2602906 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:3146785 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:3146785 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:3146785 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:3771395 1 2 43.39748 -11.4894
2L:3771395 1 2 43.2661 -11.6803
2L:3945568 1 2 43.63717 -12.302
2L:3945568 1 2 43.39032 -11.6099
```

For each SNP (`2L:647803`, `2L:2602906`, `2L:3146785`, ...), I want to have 3 rows. 
If there are not 3 rows per SNP, I would like to remove that SNP. 
This is my desired output: (`2L:3771395` and `2L:3945568` are removed as there are only two instances of each of them).

```
head desired
2L:647803 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:647803 1 2 43.63717 -12.302
2L:647803 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:2602906 1 2 43.39748 -11.4894
2L:2602906 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:2602906 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:3146785 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:3146785 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:3146785 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
```

Comment: (1) Please explicitly state (and/or show by example) what you want to happen if a “SNP id” (whatever that is) appears *more than* three times. (2) Do you guarantee that the file is sorted by SNP id? … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 4):

Inelegant but pragmatic:

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR {a[$1]++; next} a[$1]==3' data data
2L:647803 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:647803 1 2 43.63717 -12.302
2L:647803 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:2602906 1 2 43.39748 -11.4894
2L:2602906 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:2602906 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:3146785 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:3146785 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:3146785 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --nidx count-similar -g 1 then filter '$count==3' then cut -x -f count inputfile
```

you hav

```
2L:647803 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:647803 1 2 43.63717 -12.302
2L:647803 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:2602906 1 2 43.39748 -11.4894
2L:2602906 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:2602906 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
2L:3146785 1 2 44.31655 -12.2373
2L:3146785 1 2 44.43951 -12.3093
2L:3146785 1 2 43.80007 -12.3451
```

- `mlr --nidx count-similar -g 1` to count distinct field 1 values
- `then filter '$count==3'` to filter only those rows for which this count = 3
- `then cut -x -f count` to remove the count colum

Comment: Nice! I was hoping there was a clean Miller solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Here’s another `awk` (and nothing but `awk`) solution.

- It assumes that the input is collated by “SNP id”;
  i.e., all the lines with SNP id = 647 will be together.
- It does not assume that the input is sorted;
  i.e., SNP id 647 can appear before or after 2602.
- It makes only a single pass through the data.
- It does not output any data for SNP ids that appear more than three times.

```
awk '
  {
    if ($1 == last) {
        count++
        if (count <= 3) line[count] = $0
    } else {
        if (count == 3) { print line[1]; print line[2]; print line[3]; }
        last = $1
        count = 1
        line[count] = $0
    }
  }
END {   if (count == 3) { print line[1]; print line[2]; print line[3]; } }
  '
```

It simply counts the consecutive lines
that have the same value in the first field / column (`$1`)
and saves lines with that same value. 
If it encounters a new value (or the end of the input), then,
if the previous value appeared three times, it prints out the saved lines.